# make thumbnails not move (jquery hide/show, thumbs under preview div)

Tags: jquery, html, css

so basically i got me a line of small thumbnails(in a div), right under another div that holds hidden bigger images,
when i click on a thumb, current image gets .hide() from jquery, and the one i clicked on is .show()'n, very simple and working.
only problem - for a second that image disappears and before the next one appears, the preview div gets empty and all the thumbnails move all the way up to the div's place! how do i prevent it?

here's the script: 
$(document).ready(function() {

```
var current = '#s0';
var last = '#s0';

$(current).show();

$(".thumb").click(function(){
    last = current;
    current = '#s'+$(this).attr('id');
    $(last).hide(1000);
    $(current).show(1000);
    //$('#tmp').text(current+' / '+last);
});

});
```

the page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/default.css' type='text/css'>

<html>
<title>Playground</title>
<head>
    <h2>this is a test...</h2>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $images = glob("./images/*.jpg");

    echo '<div width=600 height=600 class=\'preview\' id=\'slides\'>';
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
    echo '<img class=\'slide\' id=\'s'.$i.'\' src=\''.$image.'\' width=600 height=600 />';
    $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';

    $i = 0;
    echo '<div class=\'thumbs\' id=\'thumbs\'>';
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
    echo '<img class=\'thumb\' id=\''.$i.'\' src=\''.$image.'\' width=100      height=100 />&nbsp';
    $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id=\'tmp\'/>';
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

and css:

```
.slide{
display: none;
}

body {
 color: black;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: xx-small;
 }

h2{
  text-align: center;
 }

 div{
  text-align: center;
 }
```

i cant properly paste the code here for some reason, so here s the jfiddle address, thanx a lot!
http://jsfiddle.net/EbDvk/

Comment: It's difficult to say without any of your HTML/CSS ... but my first guess would be to use `position: absolute` together with top and left to prevent this "relative" movement.

Comment: Please post the HTML that is generated by your PHP.  That way we can put it in a jsFiddle and play around with it.